# use ngmodelchange in a component that use another component

Tags: angular

I'm looking to use a change event in a component A  that use another component B , in the component B  where I have the mat-select to ckeck .

I tried this , but Ii does not call the change method.

Component A:

```
<ng-template #matCellTypeTemplate let-row="row" let-index="index">
  <ng-container *ngIf="!row.editing">
    <mat-form-field [formGroup]="row.form" [attr.types_serveur]="index" >
      <mat-select formControlName="types_serveur" [compareWith]="matSelectCompareWithId" multiple >
        <mat-option *ngFor="let type of row.form.value.types_serveur | sortBy:['ordre','libelle']" [value]="type" [disabled]="true" >
          {{ type.libelle }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="row.editing">
  <div (change)="doSomething($event)">
    <app-custom-mat-select-search
      [options]="typesServeur | sortBy:['ordre','libelle']"
      [selectFormGroup]="row.form"
      [selectFormControlName]="'types_serveur'"
      [selectCompareWith]="matSelectCompareWithId"
      [selectPlaceholder]=""
      [selectDataAccessor]="matSelectDataAccessorByLibelle"
      multiple
      >
    </app-custom-mat-select-search>
  </div>

  </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

Component B :

```
<mat-form-field [formGroup]="selectFormGroup">
  <mat-select [formControlName]="selectFormControlName"
              [compareWith]="selectCompareWith"
              [placeholder]="selectPlaceholder"
              [multiple]="multiple"
              #select>
    <mat-option>
      <ngx-mat-select-search  [formControl]="filterCtrl"
                              placeholderLabel="Rechercher..."
                              noEntriesFoundLabel="'Aucun résultat'">
        <fa-icon icon="times" class="icon" ngxMatSelectSearchClear ></fa-icon>
      </ngx-mat-select-search>
    </mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let data of filteredData | async" [value]="data" >
      {{selectDataAccessor(data)}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div (click)="doSomething($event)">
```

Comment: there is no change event for div only click event change even work for form field input property change

Comment: the function click works , but I'm looking to check if the mat-select is changed before calling the methode "doSomething($event)"

Comment: there is no change event For Div

Comment: I made an EventEmitter in the mat-option , it send the data , but it's not synchronized "it sent the value of the ckecked ckeckbox after I unchecked id"